# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{3x+1}}{2-\sqrt{5x+4}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{3x+1}}{2-\sqrt{5x+4}}$$

How do I solve this without using derivatives or integrals.

Comment: it is ^0.5. I dont know how to use mathJx

Comment: [To help you learn it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate $2+\sqrt{5x+4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the numerator and the denominator are of the form
$$
a-\sqrt{bx+a^2}
$$
(with $a>0$). In the numerator we have $a=1$, $b=3$; in the denominator we have $a=2$, $b=5$.

Let's try
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-\sqrt{bx+a^2}}{x}
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a-\sqrt{bx+a^2}}{x}
  \frac{a+\sqrt{bx+a^2}}{a+\sqrt{bx+a^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-bx}{x(a+\sqrt{bx+a^2})}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-b}{a+\sqrt{bx+a^2}}\\
&=-\frac{b}{2a}
\end{align}
Thus your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{3x+1}}{2-\sqrt{5x+4}}=
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{3x+1}}{x}\frac{x}{2-\sqrt{5x+4}}=
\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{4}{5}\right)=\frac{6}{5}
$$

---

When you'll learn Taylor expansions, you'll see that
$$
\sqrt{1+kx}=1+\frac{1}{2}kx+o(x)
$$
so
$$
\frac{1-\sqrt{1+3x}}{2-\sqrt{4+5x}}=
\frac{1-\sqrt{1+3x}}{2-2\sqrt{1+\frac{5}{4}x}}=
\frac{1-(1+\frac{3}{2}x+o(x))}{2-2(1+\frac{5}{8}x+o(x))}=
\frac{-\frac{3}{2}x+o(x)}{-\frac{5}{4}x+o(x)}=
\frac{-\frac{3}{2}+o(1)}{-\frac{5}{4}+o(1)}
$$
and so the limit is
$$
\frac{-3/2}{-5/4}=\frac{6}{5}
$$

Comment: @Nick Yes, you're right! Fixed. Note that I added $x$ factors for splitting the limit into two.

Comment: Thank you @egreg, a new way of looking at the question.

Comment: @Nick A greater part of mathematics is looking for and finding patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following steps

$$\eqalign{
  & L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{1 - {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}} \over {2 - {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{1 - {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}} \over {2 - {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}}}{{2 + {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}} \over {2 + {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}}}{{1 + {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}} \over {1 + {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{1 - (3x + 1)} \over {4 - (5x + 4)}}{{2 + {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}} \over {1 + {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{ - 3x} \over { - 5x}}{{2 + {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}} \over {1 + {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{ - 3x} \over { - 5x}}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {{2 + {{(5x + 4)}^{0.5}}} \over {1 + {{(3x + 1)}^{0.5}}}}  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\, = \left( {{3 \over 5}} \right)\left( {{4 \over 2}} \right) = {6 \over 5} \cr} $$

Comment: @Nick: Did you see this answer? :)

Comment: makes much more sense now. Thanks.